# Restore previously open project and pages when starting

Tags: delphi, ide, breakpoints

A silly question. When I exit from RAD Studio XE2 and then I start it again, I find that all the previously open things now are closed and I must restore them manually.

I would like to find already open

- the project group that was open on previous lession,
- all its open pages (source files, welcome page etc. for instance)
- breakpoints
- bookmarks

So I can continue working on it without remembering everything.

Eclipse and Visual Studio do this. How can I **make RAD Studio restore** all these things (or some of them) **on startup**?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try clicking "Auto Save Project Options" on the first page of the Tools/Options dialog.

From the help file:

> Autosaves or updates the project desktop file (.dsk file extension)
>   when you close the project or exit the product.
>
> The .dsk file records your current settings for:
>
> - Desktop layout
> - Breakpoints
> - Watch items
> - Files currently open in the IDE
>
> When you reopen the project later, the .dsk file is read, and your
>   desktop layout, your breakpoints, and your watches are all restored.
>   Also, all files that were opened when the project was closed are
>   opened again, regardless of whether they are used by the project.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to be there in Rio, do you happen to know if it is still hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

As of 10.3 Rio, you can find this option in Tools > Options > IDE > Saving and Desktop under the Autosave section,[image]